# A file is locked with an integer password that is 1 digit long

Tags: probability

A file is locked with an integer password that is 1 digit long. Each time you guess an incorrect password, the password is changed randomly to an integer 1 digit longer than the previous password. The probability distribution of the password is uniform over all possible passwords (passwords are not allowed to have a leading digit of zero).

If $P$ is the probability you eventually guess the password correctly, what is the 20th digit of $P$ after the decimal point?

At first, I thought it should be like:

1. Guessed correctly at the 1st trial: $\frac19$
2. Guessed correctly at the 2nd trial: $\frac19 + \frac89 \times \frac1{90}$
3. Guessed correctly at the 3rd trial: $\frac19 + \frac89 \times \frac1{90} + \frac89 \times \frac1{90} + \frac89 \times \frac8{90} \times \frac1{900}$

But then there is no patterns, so I think there is something wrong in my thought. Also, since the question is asking the 20th digit of $P$, I am guessing the answer should be maybe geometric series?

Is there any thoughts or advice on this? Appreciate your help!

Comment: You say you think it's a geometric series: try to find the common quotient; the factor you multiply with to get from term to term. This is the obvious next step. Add a few more terms if you need, to confirm that it is indeed geometric (at least initially). Or you might find it isn't geometric. You won't know until you try.

Comment: What type of answer are you expecting?  For instance, the value I found for $P$ is really only nicely written with the q-Pochhammer Symbol, which doesn't give a particularly nice way to find the 20th digit.  Is this a problem for which you're expected to use a computer to evaluate the answer?

Comment: First of all, thank you all for the replies! It is an interview question that is supposed to be solved in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_n$ is the probability you guess correctly at the $n$-th trial, we know that $p_1 = \frac{1}{9}$ and $p_{n+1} = (1-p_n)\frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^{n}}$.

So the $p_n$ that you're summing do not form a geometric series as the quotient of successive terms isn't constant.

But maybe this recursion will lead to a closed form for $p_n$ in terms of $n$ and a possibility to find a closed formula for the sum. But as the terms are decreasing rapidly, a small computer script (even `bc -l` on the Unix command line will do) will find the 20th decimal quite quickly. I don't know the course you're taking, but maybe that sort of approach is more warranted or feasible than the closed form approach.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for the replies! It is an interview question that is supposed to be solved in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to calculate it as the complement of the probability that you don't guess the password correctly:
$$1-\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{90}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{900}\right)\ldots=1-\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{9\cdot10^n}\right)$$

But I don't know of any easy way to approximate the [q-series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) without using a software. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+product+%281-1%2F%289*10%5En%29%29%2C+n%3D0+to+infinity) says that the digit you are looking for is 2.

Comment: First of all, thank you all for the replies! It is an interview question that is supposed to be solved in 4 minutes.

Comment: @ChangheQiao May I ask what kind of interview? What level? Is it for a math or computer science job?

Comment: It is a graduate intern for a company in financial services!

Comment: @ChangheQiao I have been thinking about it, it doesn't seem to me that a 4-minute solution is possible. Maybe you have not stated the problem properly/clearly. It may be that **a random digit is added to the previous unguessed password** for each failure, like asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206636/probability-of-guessing-the-correct-password). In which case the answer $P=1/9=0.1111\ldots$ is computable with pen and paper, and the 20th digit after the decimal point is obvious.

Comment: I double-checked the screenshot of the problem itself, but I wrote exactly what was given..yeah that is the possible case that I also thought (maybe the person who made wrote it unclear).